# Disable anti-flooding in inspIRCd

Tags: irc, ircd

How do I go about disabling anti-flooding in inspIRCd? It is only an annoyance on a private chat.

No anti-flooding modules are enabled and all flooding-limits have been set to maximum - yet it still blocks posting for example an ascii image.

Any pointers in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: you can't.

However:

> You should also include a flood="x" line which indicates the number of
>   lines a user may place into their buffer at once before they are
>   disconnected for excess flood. This feature can not be disabled,
>   however it can be set to extremely high values, rendering it
>   effectively disabled. A recommended value is 10. A counter is
>   maintained for each user which is reset every 'threshold' seconds and
>   specifying this threshold value with threshold="X" indicates how often
>   the counter is reset. For example, with flood="5" and threshold="8",
>   the user may not send more than 5 lines in 8 secs.

(Source: https://brainbox.cc/stash/projects/INSP/repos/inspircd/browse/docs/inspircd.conf.example?at=a3491c9be4bf2c9899bde9c85da9e7d2c4fd694e)

This paragraph refers to the "connect" tag in /etc/inspircd/inspircd.conf which might look like this:

```
<connect allow="*" timeout="60"
flood="999999" threshold="1"
pingfreq="120"
sendq="262144" recvq="8192"
localmax="3" globalmax="3">
```

Unfortunately, I have not yet tried this out myself. Apparently, InspIRCd has every conceivable feature except good documentation, and having a "flood" Attribute in a "connect" tags made me assume that it refers to Connection flooding, not message flooding. So after three days of searching, I just built rate limiting into my bot.